# C++ OpenGL GLEW Static Library on Windows 7 MSVC2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, windows-7, glew

I am attempting to Compile a simple OpenGL program on windows with statically linked glew32mxsd.lib...  I am also working with glfw and if I compile without glew everything works.

I Downloaded the glew src and build the static mx debug library from source.  I then copied the resulting glew32mxsd.lib file to my project directory.  I am using cmake so my cmake code appears as follows.

```
SET (GLEW_VERSION    1.9.0)
SET (GLEW_DIRECTORY  ${EXTERNAL_LIBS}/glew/${GLEW_VERSION})
SET (GLEW_INCLUDES   ${GLEW_DIRECTORY}/include)
SET (GLEW_LIBS       ${GLEW_DIRECTORY}/win/${SYSTEM_ARC}/lib)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES (${GLEW_INCLUDES})

ADD_EXECUTABLE (myproject ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(engine OpenGL32.lib)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(engine ${GLEW_LIBS}/glew32mxsd.lib)
```

Also in my source I am using the following in my header

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#define GLEW_MX
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#ifdef WIN32
  #include <GL/wglew.h>
#endif

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
static GLEWContext *glewGetContext()
{
  return nullptr;
}
```

**Everything compiles and links without any errors but...**
When I run the program I get a memory access error.  The call stack is

```
engine.exe!glewContextInit(GLEWContextStruct * ctx) Line 8912   C
engine.exe!cext::graphics::internal::WindowManager::initGLExtentions() Line 204 C++
engine.exe!cext::graphics::WindowManager::initGLExtentions() Line 273   C++
engine.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 363   C++
engine.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 536 C
engine.exe!mainCRTStartup() Line 377    C
```

And looking at line 8912 in glew.c the following line is revealed

```
CONST_CAST(GLEW_VERSION_4_3)   = ( major > 4 ) || ( major == 4 && minor >= 3 ) ? GL_TRUE : GL_FALSE;
```

My glewInit looks like the following

```
void initGLExtentions()
{
  glewExperimental = true;
  GLenum err = glewInit();
  if (GLEW_OK != err)
  {
     printf("Error: %s\n",glewGetErrorString(err));
  }
  printf("Status: Using GLEW %s\n",glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION));
  if (!GLEW_ARB_vertex_buffer_object)
  {
    printf("VBO not supported\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}
...
glfwWindow *window = makeWindow(options,hints);
if (!window)
{
  fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window\n" );
  glfwTerminate();
  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
initGLExtentions();
```

Using the same code on Mac works without a problem which leads me to believe that it is something to do with the static lib.  However even after following all the instructions on the glew website I must be missing something still.

**Edit: Additional Information**
I ran dependency walker on my application after reading about it in another thread.  Running dependency walker on my exe file produces the following missing files

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-0.DLL
DCOMP.DLL
GPSVC.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
```

These are called from the USER32.DLL.  Are these related to the glew.lib or wglew.lib in anyway?